How to find property in array of object and stop looping
I have an array of objects
const jobs = [
{   "id": 1,
    "title": "Item 1",
    "Invoice Net": "€120.00",
    "Invoice VAT": "€0.00",
    "Invoice Total": "€120.00"
},
{   "id": 2,
    "title": "Item 2",
},
{   "id": 3,
    "title": "Item 1",
    "Invoice Net": "€200.00",
    "Invoice VAT": "€20.00",
    "Invoice Total": "€240.00"
},

];
I want to loop through the array and then through its objects to find the first existing "Invoice Net" key. When the key is found I want to pass its value to the variable and stop looping.
My solution so far is
let passedValue = null;

jobs.forEach((job) => {
  if('Invoice Net' in job){
    passedValue = job['Invoice Net'];
    
}
 break;
})

It's obviously not working as the break statement is not allowed in forEach loop

use some, so that it will stop the loop as soon as the element is found

break; works fine in a normal loop, is there a reason not to use one?

This question is similar to: Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. The accepted answer contains a condition that checks for a specific ID. You can replace that condition with your condition.

const jobs = [
    { "id": 1, "title": "Item 1", "Invoice Net": "€120.00", "Invoice VAT": "€0.00", "Invoice Total": "€120.00" },
    { "id": 2, "title": "Item 2" },
    { "id": 3, "title": "Item 1", "Invoice Net": "€200.00", "Invoice VAT": "€20.00", "Invoice Total": "€240.00" }
];

let invoiceNetValue;

for (const job of jobs) {
    if (job["Invoice Net"] !== undefined) {
        invoiceNetValue = job["Invoice Net"];
        break;  // Exit the loop once the first "Invoice Net" is found
    }
}

console.log(invoiceNetValue);  // Output: "€120.00"


if (job["Invoice Net"] !== undefined) is not the same as if('Invoice Net' in job). Also please read [answer] "avoid trying to answer questions which... have already been asked and answered many times before."
